# ANDROID problem with built in reader disableing

Tags: android, nfc

`Hello,
I'm just making an NFCs timekeeping application, where I had a problem that I can't overcome, if anyone has any ideas I would be happy to hear.
When I scan the nfc tag, the built-in NFC reader for Android keeps popping up.
If I put the intent filter in the manifest file, it doesn't pop up, but then again and again with every touch it pulls in the activity for which I set, which is not appropriate and I would also use nfc for other activities, so this is not a solution.
Is there a way to prevent the built-in nfc reader from appearing?
the nfc chips only have an id, nothing else and it can no longer be changed. 
Thank you very much in advance for your help!
the code:

```
package eu.obsys.staffkeeper.ui.worklogin;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.TagLostException;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcF;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import eu.obsys.staffkeeper.FirstPageActivity;
import eu.obsys.staffkeeper.R;
import eu.obsys.staffkeeper.data.JsonObjectAsyncResponse;
import eu.obsys.staffkeeper.data.Repository;
import eu.obsys.staffkeeper.model.GpsLocation;
import eu.obsys.staffkeeper.util.GlobalFunction;

public class WorkLogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Context context;
    private Button logInToWorkCard,logOutToWorkCard, backToMenu, loginButton;
    private ImageView thumbnail;
    private String bitmapString;
    private TextView nfcContent,txtType;
    private int employeeId = 0;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
    private Drawable sampleImage;

    //NFC
    public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
    public static final String TAG = "NfcDemo";
    private Tag detectedTag;
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter[] readTagFilters;

    private String baseUrl;
    private static final String GLOBAL_DATA     = "globalShared";
    String[] perms = {"android.permission.NFC"};

    int permsRequestCode = 200;

    IntentFilter[] intentFiltersArray;

    String[][] techListsArray;
    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter();

    int loginStatus = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_log_in);
        requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        initVariable();
        initNFC();
        initListener();
    }

    public void initVariable() {
        context                 = getApplicationContext();
        sharedPreferences       = context.getSharedPreferences("placeObject", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        baseUrl                 = sharedPreferences.getString("baseUrl", "https://mng.ob-sys.eu/");

        logInToWorkCard         = findViewById(R.id.loginToWorkCard);
        logOutToWorkCard        = findViewById(R.id.logoutFromWorkCard);
        loginButton             = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        backToMenu              = findViewById(R.id.bacToMenuButton);
        thumbnail               = findViewById(R.id.PhotoThumbnail);
        nfcContent              = findViewById(R.id.nfcContent);
        nfcContent              = findViewById(R.id.nfcContent);
        nfcContent              = findViewById(R.id.nfcContent);


        sampleImage             = thumbnail.getDrawable();

        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        if(packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT) == false){
            Toast.makeText(context, "This device does not have a camera.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void takePictureAndStoreEmployeeId(int employeeIdLocal) {
        mNfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new Repository().getUserByNFC(baseUrl, employeeIdLocal, WorkLogInActivity.this, new JsonObjectAsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinished(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                try {
                    if(jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                        employeeId = employeeIdLocal;
                        loginStatus = jsonObject.getInt("loginStatus");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
                        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent,
                                CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void initListener() {

        backToMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(WorkLogInActivity.this, FirstPageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        logInToWorkCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logInToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                final int duration                    = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
//                GpsLocation gpsLocation     = GlobalFunction.getLocation(context);
                new Repository().setLoginStatus(
                        baseUrl,
                        employeeId,
                        1,
                        sharedPreferences.getInt("placeId", 0),
                        bitmapString,
                        WorkLogInActivity.this,
                        new JsonObjectAsyncResponse() {
                            @Override
                            public void processFinished(JSONObject _jsonObject) {
                                try {
                                    if(_jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                                        logInToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        resetPage();
                                    } else {
                                        logInToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        String text                   = context.getResources().getString(R.string.faultAction) + " Listener";
                                        Toast toast                   = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                        toast.show();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });

        logOutToWorkCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logOutToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Context context             = getApplicationContext();
                final int duration          = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                //GpsLocation gpsLocation     = GlobalFunction.getLocation(context);
                new Repository().setLoginStatus(
                        baseUrl,
                        employeeId,
                        0,
                        sharedPreferences.getInt("placeId", 0),
                        bitmapString,
                        WorkLogInActivity.this,
                        new JsonObjectAsyncResponse() {
                            @Override
                            public void processFinished(JSONObject _jsonObject) {
                                try {
                                    if(_jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                                        logOutToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        resetPage();
                                    } else {
                                        logOutToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        String text                   = context.getResources().getString(R.string.faultAction) + " Listener";
                                        Toast toast                   = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                        toast.show();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                // convert byte array to Bitmap
                bitmapString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                        byteArray.length);
                if(loginStatus == 1) {
                    logInToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    logOutToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    logInToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    logOutToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
//                loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    public void resetPage() {
        thumbnail.setImageDrawable(sampleImage);
        logInToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        logOutToWorkCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void initNFC() {
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndef.addDataType("*/*");    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches.
                                       You should specify only the ones that you need. */
        }
        catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
        }
        intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
        techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };

        try {
            if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                txtType.setText("NFC is disabled.");
            } else {
                //txtType.setText("érkngorbgobrogb");
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /**
         * It's important, that the activity is in the foreground (resumed). Otherwise
         * an IllegalStateException is thrown.
         */
        if(mNfcAdapter!= null) {

            //mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, techListsArray);
            Bundle options = new Bundle();
            // Work around for some broken Nfc firmware implementations that poll the card too fast
            options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);

            // Enable ReaderMode for all types of card and disable platform sounds
            mNfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this,
                    this,
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
                    options);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        /**
         * Call this before onPause, otherwise an IllegalArgumentException is thrown as well.
         */
        if(mNfcAdapter!= null)
            mNfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(permsRequestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (permsRequestCode) {

            case 200:

                boolean nfcAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                break;

        }

    }

    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {

        // Read and or write to Tag here to the appropriate Tag Technology type class
        // in this example the card should be an Ndef Technology Type
        Ndef mNdef = Ndef.get(tag);

        // Check that it is an Ndef capable card
        if (mNdef != null) {

            // If we want to read
            // As we did not turn on the NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK
            // We can get the cached Ndef message the system read for us.

            NdefMessage mNdefMessage = mNdef.getCachedNdefMessage();
            String anyad = "";
            NdefRecord[] records = mNdefMessage.getRecords();
            for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
                //if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
                byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();

                // Get the Text Encoding
                String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";

                // Get the Language Code
                int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

                // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
                // e.g. "en"

                // Get the Text
                try {
                    anyad = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // }
            }
            // Or if we want to write a Ndef message

            // Create a Ndef Record
            //NdefRecord mRecord = NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", "2");

            // Add to a NdefMessage
//            NdefMessage mMsg = new NdefMessage(mRecord);
//
            // Catch errors
            try {
                mNdef.connect();
//                mNdef.writeNdefMessage(mMsg);
                    takePictureAndStoreEmployeeId(Integer.parseInt(anyad));
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Read NFC Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Make a Sound
                try {
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
                            notification);
                    r.play();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Some error playing sound
                }

            //} catch (FormatException e) {
                // if the NDEF Message to write is malformed
            } catch (TagLostException e) {
                // Tag went out of range before operations were complete
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // if there is an I/O failure, or the operation is cancelled
            } finally {
                // Be nice and try and close the tag to
                // Disable I/O operations to the tag from this TagTechnology object, and release resources.
                try {
                    mNdef.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // if there is an I/O failure, or the operation is cancelled
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer as you don't supply full details of what data is on the card.

But it is possible the problem is that you `disableReaderMode` in `takePictureAndStoreEmployeeId` method which is called from `onTagDiscovered` so once you read the NFC Tag once, you will never read NFC Tags again because Reader Mode is never re-enabled.

Remember NFC interaction can be triggered multiple times as you present a Tag.
So likely that what is happening is you present the Tag it triggers `onTagDiscovered` which then `disableReaderMode` and then on the second trigger the system is free to display the default system NFC dialog because you have told it you are no longer interested in receiving NFC triggers.

Solution is probably don't `disableReaderMode` in `takePictureAndStoreEmployeeId`

Also your code also has a lot of unused stuff in it, you setup for the old foreground NFC method `enableForegroundDispatch` which is never used (because it is replaced by using `enableReaderMode` and you should not use both at once)

Comment: The tag just contains a number in text/plain. 
I have tried that too but it is making the same situaltion :(.
And there is a main problem why I put the disable there because the users conplaining about the process that why is a problem that they put the tag to the phone several times. :(

So somehow I wanted to try to prevent the process to start every time when tag is discovered. If have a solution how can I do that I am open to it. :)

Comment: The solution to only processing the Tag when you want to and once is to use something like a global variable or variable in ViewModal to store a flag that is changed state when you have successfully processed the Tag once. Then in `onTagDiscovered` you have "if flag is not set then process Tag else do nothing". I would also recommend for best user experience is that all Activities in an NFC app use `enableReaderMode`, if an Activity does not do anything with NFC then `onTagDiscovered` is empty.

Comment: I will try this out but sound good :)